# Azure function (VS2017) SQL table binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to bind data from AF to Azure SQL. It's easy to do in Azure Portal adding the binding params in function.json file

```
 {
  "type": "apiHubTable",
  "name": "outputTable",
  "dataSetName": "default",
  "tableName": "SpeechToText",
  "connection": "sql_SQL",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

But I cant do this in VS2017 preview( 
Binding to Azure SQL is unavailable)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub` NuGet package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub -Version 1.0.0-beta3 -Pre
```

and then use `ApiHubTable` attribute for your binding

```
[ApiHubTable("sql_SQL", DataSetName = "default", TableName = "SpeechToText")]
```

Comment: And what is the type for the parameter, then?

Comment: @bc3tech I assume `ITable<MyRow>`, see example in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-table)

Comment: actually looks like IAsyncCollector<T>, because trying to use ITable in the portal is problematic due to reference library and namespace ambiguities

Comment: @Mikhail Where does one find the documentation for the `ApiHubTableAttribute` class?  Is this open source?  I only find an example of its usage from a GitHub search: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Serverless-computing-in-Azure-with-.NET/blob/1d55ad1008f0473785ffb533ac0f239563ed723b/Chapter04/TextEvaluation/AverageResults.cs